# Reassign value to a list Elixir

Tags: list, enums, elixir

I have a structure (data) where the real values are dependent about the customer is making the request, but I am not able to reassign them. This is my code:

The base structure:

```
Party: [
  Sender: [

  ]
]
```

And an example about the real values of a customer:

```
Party: [
  Sender: [
    AgentUserSender: [
      Name: "The_name",
      Type: "The_type",
      OtherIDs: [
        {:OtherID, %{Description: "value"}, "_value"},
        {:OtherID, %{Description: "value_1"}, "_value_1"}
      ],
      OtherKey: "other_value"
    ]
  ]
]
```

And how I (poorly) trying to do:

```
data[:Party][:Sender] = customer[:Party][:Sender]
```

There is another added problem: not all customers has the same fields on the structure. This is other example, of other customer:

```
Party: [
  Sender: [
    TravelAgencySender: [
      Name: "NAME",
      IATA_Number: "xxxxxxxx",
      AgencyID: "agency"
    ]
  ]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What’s wrong with just using `customer` as `data`? Why do you need to update a basically empty object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is this:

```
> data = [Party: [Sender: []]]
[Party: [Sender: []]]
> data = put_in(data[:Party][:Sender], ["something"])
[Party: [Sender: ["something"]]]
```

or this:

```
> data = [Party: [Sender: ["something"]]]
[Party: [Sender: ["something"]]]
> data = put_in(data[:Party][:Sender], data[:Party][:Sender] ++ ["something_else"])
[Party: [Sender: ["something", "something_else"]]]

#Alternatively update_in instead of put_in
> data = [Party: [Sender: ["something"]]]
[Party: [Sender: ["something"]]]
> data = update_in(data[:Party][:Sender], &(&1 ++ ["something_else"]))
[Party: [Sender: ["something", "something_else"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to use [`Keyword.get_and_update/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.3/elixir/Keyword.html#get_and_update/3):

```
iex(1)> mine = [Party: [ Sender: [ ]]]
iex(2)> cust = [Party: [ Sender: [ .......... ]]]

iex(3)> { _, data } = mine |> Keyword.get_and_update(:Party, fn party ->
...(3)>   { _, result } = mine[:Party]
...(3)>     |> Keyword.get_and_update(:Sender, fn sender ->
...(3)>          { sender, cust[:Party][:Sender] }
...(3)>        end)
...(3)>   { party, result }
...(3)> end)

iex(4)> data
  [Party: [Sender: [AgentUserSender: [Name: "The_name", Type: "The_type",
     OtherIDs: [{:OtherID, %{Description: "value"}, "_value"},
                {:OtherID, %{Description: "value_1"}, "_value_1"}],
     OtherKey: "other_value"]]]]
```

If you want to merge values, or modify it in some sophisticated way, just modify

```
{ sender, cust[:Party][:Sender] }
```

line to return what is needed as second tuple item (the first is to be the value got, and hence is to be left intact.)